# Fixing Fill in geom_hex

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I'm struggling to get geom_hex to fill with a certain variable. My goal is to get geom_hex to fill with the variable xRV, with lower values being red and higher values being blue, but as things stand all I get is gray hexagons.

Here's the df:

```
IVB <- c(10, 15, 20, 17, 17.5, 20, 17, 16.5, 21.3, 12.5, 10.9)
RelZ <- c(66, 75, 70, 67, 68.3, 67.6, 70.3, 72, 65.3, 55.6, 71)
xRV <- c(-.01, .13, -.15, .5, -.03, -.06, .07, .1, -.02, .05, .01)
miheat <- data.frame(IVB, RelZ, xRV)
```

Here's the code I've been running that hasn't been working:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hexbin)
ggplot(miheat, aes(x = RelZ, y = IVB)) + geom_hex(aes(fill = xRV)) + scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red" , mid = "white" , high = "blue", space = "Lab")
```

[Here's what the output looks like when I run the code above on all of the df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMKvZ.png)

Comment: @Ben That does work to fix the fill, but the formatting isn't where I want it to be. Ideally I'd like to have the same formatting as the image linked above just with the proper fill. This fills, but turns the hexagons into very small points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close in what you were doing in your question. Instead of using `fill` what you should be doing is using `weight`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hexbin)
ggplot(miheat,aes(x = RelZ, y = IVB, weight = xRV)) + geom_hex() + scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red" , mid = "white" , high = "blue", space = "Lab", midpoint = 0)
```

[image: example]